# What is this angle in a right triangle with sides of length 5, 12, and 13?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I find the missing adjacent angle to leg b in a right triangle with the following side lengths: leg a = 5, leg b = 12, and hypotenuse = 13.

Thanks

Comment: What do you know about $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that your triangle is a right triangle, denote your angle $\theta$ (the angle you need, assuming it's the angle that leg b forms with the hypotenuse), and use the definition of $\sin \theta$ or $\cos \theta$ or $\tan \theta$ as each is defined in terms of the lengths of the sides you are given.

Any one of these trig functions of $\theta$ can be used, as you are given the lengths of the side opposite the angle (a), adjacent to the angle (b), and the hypotenuse (h).

Example: $$\sin \theta = \frac{\text{opposite side length }}{\text{hypotenuse side length}} = \frac{a}{h} = \frac{5}{13}$$

$$\small \left(\cos\theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{12}{13},\;\;\tan\theta = \dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \frac{5}{12}\right)$$

Then solve for $\theta$, knowing $$\theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac {5}{13}\right) = \arcsin\left(\dfrac{5}{13}\right)$$

---

The above relationships between the lengths of the sides of a right triangle and $\cos\theta, \sin\theta, \tan\theta$ should become "second nature" to you.

There are mnemonics that can help you memorize/remember this. For example, the mnemonic I learned was:

$$\text{"The Old Arab Sat On His Camel And Hiccuped"}\iff $$ $$ \text{ Tan = Opposite/Adjacent, Sin = Opposite/Hypotenuse, Cos = Adjacent/Hypotenuse}.$$

There are other such mnemonics that exist, as well, and perhaps others can post them as comments below!

---

**Resources**

See [**Right-Angled Trigonometry**](http://thomaswhitham.pbworks.com/f/Right%20Angled%20Trigonometry.pdf), a pdf document you can open and/or download that covers the concepts need to solve problems like the one you posted.

See [**this link**](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/basirati.htm) to better understand how to solve these kinds of questions. E.g., To answer this question, it suffices to know the lengths of two sides of the right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

So you're referring to the angle opposite leg a, which we'll call angle A.  We have

$$\sin A=\frac ac=\frac5{13}$$

To find the measurement of the angle, we need to use the inverse sine function, yielding

$$A=\sin^{-1}\frac5{13}$$

I don't think there's any way to simplify that, but if you want an approximate value, you can probably compute it with a scientific calculator.

Comment: It is known that $\frac{A}{\pi}$ is irrational, so not "nice"....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\sin(A)=\frac{5}{13}$, $\cos(A)=\frac{12}{13}$, and $\tan(A)=\frac{5}{12}$. $A$ can be found using the inverse of $\sin$, $\cos$, or $\tan$.